# Order of WHERE conditions in SQL query makes difference

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables `Student` and `Class`.

In `Student` table, the fields are `studentNo, studentName, classNo`

In `Class` table, fields are `classNo, className, teacherName`

what I am trying to do is construct a query to list all students who are in the `history` class.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT studentName
FROM Student s, Class c
WHERE s.classNo = c.classNo AND
   c.className = ‘history’;
```

But I am not 100% sure about the above query. and I am thinking maybe the following one can work than the above one:

```
SELECT studentName
FROM Student s, Class c
WHERE c.className = ‘history’ AND
   s.classNo = c.classNo;
```

Can anyone help me find the correct query to this problem? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query seems fine but mind if you convert it into `ANSI SQL_92` format (*more clear, and may not lead to cross join*),

```
SELECT studentName
FROM Student s INNER JOIN Class c
       ON s.classNo = c.classNo
WHERE  c.className = 'history';
```

There is no difference if you interchange the two. In math, `commutative` law states that `A + B = B + A`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

StudentName

FROM Student St JOIN Class c
                              ON St.classNo = c.classNo
WHERE  c.className = 'history'